# how to query from big data so fast?

Tags: sql, linux, social-networking

Halo all,

i want my user to get all his friend list information from facebook, then search anything about that data. but i want it to be fast.

for example : user A has 20 friends name B to W. He want to know which of his friends who are sagitarius.

my normal process would be :

1. get list of all friend's name  and  birthday (using facebook API).
2. save to database (mysql)
3. query (use mysql) which from the list who has birthday from nov 22 - dec 22.

well, i did this but it takes too much time. and i want to make it faster. i think it's because i have to save it all to database first.

if only there is a way to query from an array, or i can save these data to RAM and search from it i think it would be much faster.

do you guys have any solution for me ???

thx Alot

Ari

Comment: "it takes too much time. and i want to make it faster. i think it's because i have to save it all to database first." Are you sure? How long does it take to retrieve the values from Facebook? How long does it take to save the values to the database? How long does the total process currently take? How long do you want it to take?

Comment: Yes, I have a solution for you. Measure how long it takes to get the data from Facebook, how long it takes to save the data to the database and how long it takes to query the data. See which one is slow, then try to make that one faster. (By the way, 99% bet that getting the data from FB is the slow part)

Comment: yes you're right, the fb part is slow, but still the one that i can improve is part to save to database and part to query from database. so, is it possible for me to save it to memori (RAM) and search from it ?

Answer (score 0):

The first step in any optimization is to know where the time is spent. There can be no general/obvious solution - otherwise, nothing would be slow because everyone would get it right in the first place and the problem wouldn't exist.

So you will have to sit down, add profiling code to your app, run some tests and come back when you've found out where the time is spent. Then we might be of further assistance.

Comment: thx aaron, the process that took big time is "get data to facebook". i improve that by using paralel process.(i cannot think any other solution beside that, any idea ???)  but i want to increase speed to save data and query data. i think save to memory and query from memori would be much faster, thats why i want to know if there's any way to do that

Comment: The question is too generic; there are thousands of ways to achieve what you want but each solution depends on some details. You can try caching, proxying, clustering, or write your own thing. It depends on how complex your queries are, how much data there is, thousands of things. A simple solution could be to dump the data to a text file and use a text editor to search it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the Facebook API contains such a feature already?

but if you're going to dump the Facebook friends DB into MySQL there is a high chance of getting a result once a month.

You can speed up stuff by execute calculations in parallel. So you may have a look into NoSQL databases or Apache Hadoop.

But be prepared, a lot of buzzwords in that area at the moment :)

Comment: thx wemu, i have read hadoop, and other but still don't understand how to translate mysql to  noSQL format, so i would hope there would be any other solution :D

Comment: well the approach is quite different, that is very true. But it is not landing on the moon. If you can understand SQL the stuff that happens in NoSQL databases shouldnt be too difficult.
I would first investigate how much data there is. Even 'a lot' can mean its just a few GB of data that easily fits into MySQL.
If you need to do "group by" with millions of rows consider Map/Reduce for speed (some sort of brute force "group by")